# Customizing the setError icon for EditText kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I Am using TextInputLayout. I try this but the icon is not shown. Help me to visible errorIcon in TextInputLayout.
I want to set a setError method to my EditText, with a custom icon instead of the default Android icon. So I tried this:

Thanks in Advance

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilFirstName"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/civProfileImage"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_twenty_four"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_twenty_four"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_sixteen"
                android:hint="@string/first_name"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_input_layout_hint_color"
                android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="5dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="5dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="5dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="5dp"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color"
                app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/colorRed"
                app:errorTextColor="@color/colorRed"
                app:hintEnabled="true">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtFirstlName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@#!$%"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextNormal"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_sixteen" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

```
        val drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_error) as Drawable
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.intrinsicWidth, drawable.intrinsicHeight)
        tilFirstName.error = getString("Error", Drawable)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? `tilFirstName.error = getString("Error", Drawable)` doesn't look right because you can't use the `Drawable` class as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `setErrorIconDrawable` method in the `TextInputLayout`:

```
   tilFirstName.error = "Error text!!";
   tilFirstName.setErrorIconDrawable(R.drawable.xxxx);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `app:errorIconDrawable` in the xml file or use `setErrorIconDrawable(Drawable)` to the TextInputLayout in the kotlin file.

Comment: tilFirstName.errorIconDrawable = drawable try this but couldnot get the result

Comment: Try it like this: `tilFirstName.setErrorIconDrawable(drawable)`

Comment: @Aashis For us to be helpful, you have to be more specific than "could not get the result".